# MongoDB: Finding a data by its ObjectId returns an empty response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, backend, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to get a data from a mongoDB Atlas database using node.JS. I have this function which searches posts by its ObjectId.

```
  static async getPostByID(id){
    let cursor;

    try {
      cursor = await db.coll.find({"_id" : ObjectId(id)});

      const post = await cursor.toArray();
      console.log({ post });
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(`Error in PostsDAO getPostByID: ${e}`);
    }

    // tried logging the **cursor** here as well but it returned an empty array
  }
```

When I try to log the response, it shows an empty response. I have a similar get request function also and it works fine. Where could the error be coming from? (Sorry I just started learning backend)

Comment: Did you verify the value of the `id` input to the method?

Comment: Yup. It has a console.log(id) in the beginning but I removed it for the sake of this post.

Comment: Is there a document with that id in the collection?

Comment: ```find``` itself returns an array, why are you converting it to array again?